# Scalar showing up as missing value in Stata

Tags: stata

I have some code that cycles through values in some nested `foreach` loops to simulate a conditional summation. Unfortunately, this seems to be creating a missing value which I can confirm by using

```
display `var'
```

I have tried searching for `+=` operator in Stata but I do not find one.
I am also confused by this behavior.
I tried assigning 10 to `topTerm` instead of 0 to see if the variable was floored but that was not the case.

```
tempname topTerm bottomTerm controlledContrast
scalar `topTerm' = 0

foreach … numlist {
  foreach … numlist {
    foreach … numlist {
              display `delta', `topTerm'
              scalar `topTerm'= `topTerm' + `delta'*`cc_difference_in_means'*`cc_vet_n'
              display `topTerm'
}}}
```

EDIT: Tried using local/global and still getting missing values. Seems to be a problem of scope, though I figured local would fix that so I'm really confused…

Note that this works from command line:

```
local x = 10
local x = `x' + 10
display `x'
>> 20
```

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you want to achieve here. You're `foreach`s are incomplete (probably hiding some source of your problem). Maybe you can reformulate your problem. What do you mean by "typing in 10 instead of 0" ? Are there no variables involved ?

Comment: @refp16 - I tested that the foreach was working by first creating all of them and then doing a display for each of the vars they creates. My problem is specifically with the the missing value of topTerm which is returned as a '.' when I try display `topTerm'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@refp16 has an excellent answer in the circumstances, but your question boils down to

1. I am summing a scalar in a series of nested loops.
2. The answer is missing.
3. This surprises me.

Only answers of the form "Look again at your data and your code" are possible here in general. In detail, there is not much that can be added except

- Stata has no `+=` operator. This is perhaps a surprise given Stata's evident fondness for C-like constructs, but it is immaterial here. `+=` would allow you to shorten your code slightly, but it would not change your problem.
- For a sum to go missing, it is necessary (and sufficient) for at least one of the values fed to that sum to be missing, for which in turn the possibilities include (a) it being missing (b)  your doing something like taking the square root of a negative number (c) your referring to something that does not exist, which Stata evaluates as missing.

The best way to debug this is to `display` each term being added and find out which one is missing. You seem to be doing this, so why can't you identify terms that are missing?

Longer term for you, know that Stata has several ways of getting sums without loops, including `summarize, meanonly`, which leaves the sum of a variable behind as `r(sum)`, and the `sum()` function which can be used in Mata for vectors and matrices.

Answer (score 2):

I can only imagine what you're trying to do. The following, using locals, works:

```
local topterm 0
local delta 5
local cc_difference_in_means 10
local cc_vet_n 25

foreach num1 of numlist 1/10 {
        local topterm = `topterm' + `delta' * `cc_difference_in_means' * `cc_vet_n'
        display `topterm'
}
```

The following also works although I admit I don't use anything other than "locals/globals". It is similar to your setup.

```
tempname topTerm
scalar `topTerm' = 0
disp `topTerm'

foreach num1 of numlist 1/10 {
        scalar `topTerm' = `topTerm' + 5
        display `topTerm'
}
```

But you might as well do this which gives the same (displayed) results:

```
scalar topTerm = 0

foreach num1 of numlist 1/10 {  
        scalar topTerm = topTerm + 5
        display topTerm
}
```

Again, I don't see what you're going for.